# Spatie - Laravel Permission - Cannot install in laravel 8.x

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-permission

Here is a error Log: Please Help me out!

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\moviedb> composer require spatie/laravel-permission
Using version ^3.17 for spatie/laravel-permission
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for spatie/laravel-permission ^3.17 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-permission[3.17.0].
    - Installation request for zizaco/entrust  5.2.x-dev -> satisfiable by zizaco/entrust[5.2.x-dev].
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v8.11.2, required as ^8.0) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.11.2].
    - spatie/laravel-permission 3.17.0 requires illuminate/auth ^5.8|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.11.2, 5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev, 7.x-dev, 8.x-dev, v8.0.0, v8.0.1, v8.0.2, v8.0.3, v8.0.4, v8.1.0, v8.10.0, v8.11.0, v8.11.1, v8.2.0, v8.3.0, v8.4.0, v8.5.0, v8.6.0, v8.7.0, v8.7.1, v8.8.0, v8.9.0], illuminate/auth[5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev, 7.x-dev, 8.x-dev, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.19, v6.18.2, v6.18.20, v6.18.21, v6.18.22, v6.18.23, v6.18.24, v6.18.25, v6.18.26, v6.18.27, v6.18.28, v6.18.29, v6.18.3, v6.18.30, v6.18.31, v6.18.32, v6.18.33, v6.18.34, v6.18.35, v6.18.36, v6.18.37, v6.18.38, v6.18.39, v6.18.4, v6.18.40, v6.18.41, v6.18.42, v6.18.43, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.19.0, v6.19.1, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.20.0, v7.21.0, v7.22.0, v7.22.1, v7.22.2, v7.22.3, v7.22.4, v7.23.0, v7.23.1, v7.23.2, v7.24.0, v7.25.0, v7.26.0, v7.26.1, v7.27.0, v7.28.0, v7.28.1, v7.28.2, v7.28.3, v7.28.4, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2, v8.0.0, v8.0.1, v8.0.2, v8.0.3, v8.0.4, v8.1.0, v8.10.0, v8.11.0, v8.11.1, v8.11.2, v8.2.0, v8.3.0, v8.4.0, v8.5.0, v8.6.0, v8.7.0, v8.7.1, v8.8.0, v8.9.0].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.8.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[6.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[7.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[8.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.0.0, 5.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.0.1, 5.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.0.2, 5.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.0.3, 5.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.0.4, 5.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.1.0, 5.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.10.0, 5.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.11.0, 5.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.11.1, 5.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.11.2, 5.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.2.0, 5.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.3.0, 5.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.4.0, 5.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.5.0, 5.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.6.0, 5.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.7.0, 5.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.7.1, 5.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.8.0, 5.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.9.0, 5.7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.7.x-dev, v8.11.2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.7.x-dev, v8.11.2].
    - don't install illuminate/auth 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth 6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth 7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth 8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.36|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.0.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.0.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.0.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.0.3|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.0.4|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.1.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.10.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.11.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.12.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.13.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.13.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.14.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.15.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.15.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.16.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.17.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.17.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.10|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.11|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.12|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.13|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.14|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.15|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.16|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.17|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.18|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.19|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.20|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.21|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.22|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.23|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.24|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.25|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.26|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.27|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.28|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.29|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.3|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.30|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.31|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.32|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.33|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.34|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.35|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.36|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.37|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.38|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.39|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.4|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.40|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.41|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.42|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.43|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.5|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.6|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.7|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.8|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.18.9|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.19.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.19.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.2.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.3.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.4.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.5.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.5.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.5.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.6.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.6.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.6.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.7.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v6.8.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.0.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.0.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.0.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.0.3|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.0.4|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.0.5|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.0.6|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.0.7|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.0.8|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.1.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.1.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.1.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.1.3|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.10.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.10.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.10.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.10.3|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.11.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.12.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.13.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.14.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.14.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.15.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.16.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.16.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.17.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.17.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.17.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.18.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.19.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.19.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.2.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.2.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.2.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.20.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.21.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.22.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.22.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.22.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.22.3|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.22.4|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.23.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.23.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.23.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.24.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.25.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.26.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.26.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.27.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.28.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.28.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.28.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.28.3|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.28.4|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.3.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.4.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.5.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.5.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.5.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.6.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.6.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.6.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.7.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.7.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.8.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.8.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.9.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.9.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v7.9.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v8.0.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v8.0.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v8.0.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v8.0.3|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v8.0.4|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v8.1.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v8.10.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v8.11.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v8.11.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v8.11.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v8.2.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v8.3.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v8.4.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v8.5.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v8.6.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v8.7.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v8.7.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v8.8.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/auth v8.9.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - Conclusion: install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\moviedb> akshunit@gmail.com
```

Hello I am working with my project in Laravel is anyone can help is really appriciated

i want to add a repo for user role managemnet system. I am using a Spatie Laravel Repo fro github.
Is Spatie Laravel Permission is working with Laravel 8.x If so then what is the problem while installing the package!

There is no issue solution in the github issue tab!

Please let me know what i am missing!

Comment: There's a mention `zizaco/entrust` in this message which does not support laravel 8 (and seems to be doing the same job as the spatie package). Is that in your composer.json also?

Comment: yes its is in composer.json file

Comment: well... you need to remove it. It doesn't work with Laravel 8

Comment: thanks man that worked fine! i just have to remove zizaco/entrust from compser.json

Answer (score 1):

```
spatie/laravel-permission 3.17.0 requires illuminate/auth
```

Did you require laravel/ui and run `php artisan ui vue --auth`

Also, why do you have zizaco/entrust & spatie/laravel-permissions? There could be conflicts there as well.

I just installed spatie/laravel-permissions on Laravel 8 and it works fine.
Given that the issue is with your composer.json, I'd like to suggest providing us with the contents of the file.